# get text from another file and include into another function

Tags: php

I've found a function to spin text while browsing.
When you then, at the end, input the following line:

```
 echo spin('{This|Here} is {some|a little bit of} {example|sample} text.');
```

Then it will give you eg. "This is a little bit of example test."

Now, I'd like to pull the text I'd like to spin from another file, so that "{This|Here} is {some|a little bit of} {example|sample} text." is in eg. spintext.php. I can't really make it to work. Because eg. the following (and different variations on this) doesn't work:

```
 $text = include("/home/domainpath/public_html/files/spintext.php"); 
 echo spin('.$text.');
```

Hope someone can point out what's wrong with the above.

Comment: What is there inside spintext.php?

Comment: Just the following: {This|Here} is {some|a little bit of} {example|sample} text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
 $text = file_get_contents("/home/domainpath/public_html/files/spintext.php"); 
 echo spin($text);
```

Comment: @Cicada OP states that the raw text is present in the PHP file.

Comment: The OP's post hints at that the contents of the spintext.php is the actual text, not PHP code, although it's badly named. The reason it won't work is because `'.$text.'` should be just `$text`.

Comment: Yeah, the raw text is in .php, but shouldn't matter I guess. The answer gives .$text. as result and not the spun text unfortunately.

Comment: @Steven Did you try the edited answer? `'.$text.'` would be literally just that, but `$text` alone gives the contents of the file.

Comment: @Juhana

Great. It actually works without ''. So just: echo spin($text);

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a return value in your include file:

test.php

```
$text = "blah blah blah....";
return $text;
```

Then use it like this:

```
$mytext = include 'test.php';
```

You can visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php. Check **Example #5 include() and the return() statement**

Comment: If it's not working in this way so just visit the link and example that I included in answer to ensure that I'm wrong.